# How to force the update of a gem with bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bundler

I have a private git server hosting a gem we developed. The gem got some commits, but the version did not actually change.

How can I force bundler to update my gem even if the version hasn't changed?

I tried "bundler update mygemname" but it did not update anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

that will not work - there is no "force" option - you will have to modify your .gemspec file  and increase the version number, then do `gem build ...`, and `bundle install`

It is critical for bundler to be able to read the version number from your gem, which was introduced in the `.gemspec` file. It's confusing not only to bundler or `gem update` , but also confusing to people if you forget to update the version number in the .gemspec file.  They would end up having gem-files lying around, and not be able to tell which versions they are, e.g. which one is newer?  (of course you could use md5-sum, but that's beside the point here).

The best thing to do is to correct the mistake in the .gemspec file, and re-release the gem.

Check the bundler source code for available options:

e.g.: `bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/cli.rb`

(search for `desc "install"`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know it's better to increase gem version, but it implies that you have to change the host application to reference the new version of the gem. Or maybe I can simply put gem "mygemname" in the gemfile so it will always fetch the latest version.

Comment: You can always run `bundle update` to update to the latest version of your gem!  Which version of Rails do you use? if you have a Gemfile, you can put this syntax `gem 'mygemname' , '>=0.5.0' `   See: http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html and http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-update.1.html

Comment: There *is* a `--force` option (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37982573/2063546)) and it works.

Comment: @Ian it looks like the --force option is a new addition to the 'gem' command. In 2011 it did not exist.

Comment: the time when you search something and then stumble upon your own answer 

Answer (score 27):

you can also put the git hashref right in the Gemfile with the `:ref` option

```
gem 'foo', :git => 'git://github.com/foobar/foo.git', :branch => '0.9-beta', :ref => '9af382ed'
```

especially useful if you don't have control over said gem, and keeps bundler from giving you a newer version in case there are breaking changes.

Answer (score 16):

First of all, don't do that. If you change your gem, you should be updating its version number. Otherwise, it's just confusing.

If you really want to do this, however, you can apply the giant hammer of removing your gem first.

```
$ gem uninstall foo
$ bundle update
```

Comment: yes, you're right, this would work, but the only time I'd do that is when testing and fixing problems in a gem before it is released. e.g. you create the gem file, install it to test it, then immediately delete the gemfile -- without trace. That's basically a pre-release version, and you should put a pre-release version in the .gemspec file in that case.

Comment: this works only if the gem was installed locally, not if it was installed using bundler in a specific application.

Comment: What "this" are you referring to? My answer or Tilo's comment? Because my answer should always work. If the gem is missing, it will get reinstalled via update.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't really clear! "this" meant your post, where as you cannot do a "gem uninstall" on a gem that was only bundled with bundler and was not installed using "gem install".

Comment: Of course you can. `gem uninstall` will uninstall a gem regardless of how it was installed in the first place. I suspect you might have the gem installed more than once, maybe as root and under your user's personal gem directory, which might be causing confusion. I would, of course, suggest that you use rvm to keep this from happening.

Comment: Might be that. But when I do a gem list 'mygemname', it says no gem exists with that name.

Comment: This won't work because the gem wasn't installed from RubyForge, it was installed with Bundler, using `gem 'projectgem', :git => ...` in the Gemfile, and goes into the .bundler/ or vendor/bundler/ directory. `gem` command doesn't know about it.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I'm developing a gem locally. I don't want to update the version each time I make a local bug fix. +100 if I could.

Answer (score 10):

From version 1.11 `bundle install` just has a `--force` option that will redownload every gem even if they are already installed.

Comment: $bundle install --force
Unknown switches '--force'

Comment: Are you using bundler 1.10 or before? It was added in 1.11, if the documentation is correct: http://bundler.io/v1.15/man/bundle-install.1.html

Comment: This flag is now named `--redownload` for what it's worth, but using `--force` will work fine still and simply warn that it is deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't answer the exact question above, but I was searching for "How to force update a gem in bundler" on Google and this came up.

I'm not trying to force update a gem to rubygems.org but rather I'm trying to reinstall a gem that's installed to a bundle path on my local system. Specifically I'm trying reinstall a gem with a native extension (nokogiri).

How I removed it from my project is as follows; assuming your `--path` is `vendor/bundle` and you're in the project's root, run:

```
find vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0 -name "*nokogiri*" -depth 2
```

Verify these files/directories are specific to nokogiri and then remove them with:

```
find vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0 -name "*nokogiri*" -depth 2 | xargs rm -rf
```

Now you can run your bundle install command as usual:

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

**Note:** You'll of course need to change `2.0.0` above to your ruby version. `ls vendor/bundle/ruby` to see which version bundler has installed gems for.